# Exit code 137 (interrupted by signal 9: SIGKILL) when writing large dictionary into CSV

Tags: python, pandas, csv, dictionary

using the code below, I read a large amount of XML files (around 300.000) into a nested dictionary. I want to write this into a single CSV file. At first attempt I did this by using a pandas dataframe as intermediary. The dictionary is fully constructed, however during the last step, when converting into CSV I get `exit code 137 (interrupted by signal 9: SIGKILL)`.
(I found that building a nested dictionary instead of appending a dataframe is by far the quickest option).

Any idea how I can manage to write into a single CSV by circumventing this error? Is there a way to free up some memory somewhere in between?

Thanks!

```
#Import packages.

import pandas as pd
from lxml import etree
import os
from os import listdir
from os.path import isfile, join
from tqdm import tqdm
from datetime import datetime

from collections import defaultdict

#Set options for displaying results
pd.set_option('display.max_rows', None)
pd.set_option('display.max_columns', None)
pd.set_option('display.width', None)
pd.set_option('display.max_colwidth', None)


def run(file, content):
    data = etree.parse(file)

    #get all paths from the XML
    get_path = lambda x: data.getpath(x)
    paths = list(map(get_path, data.getroot().getiterator()))
    content = ""
    content = [
        data.getroot().xpath(path)
        for path in paths
    ]

    get_text = lambda x: x.text

    content = [list(map(get_text, i)) for i in content]
    content = dict(zip(paths, content))
    content = {
        content["/clinical_study/id_info/nct_id"][0]: content
    }
    dict_final.update(content)


def write_csv(df_name, csv):
    df_name.to_csv(csv, sep=";")


#######RUN######

mypath = '/Users/Documents/AllPublicXML'

folder_all = os.listdir(mypath)

dict_final = {}
df_final = pd.DataFrame()

for folder in tqdm(folder_all):

    mypath2 = mypath + "/" + folder
    print(folder)

    if os.path.isdir(mypath2):
        file = [f for f in listdir(mypath2) if isfile(join(mypath2, f))]
        output = "./Output/" + folder + ".csv"
        for x in tqdm(file):
            dir = mypath2 + "/" + x
            #output = "./Output/"+x+".csv"
            dict_name = x.split(".", 1)[0]
            try:
                run(dir,dict_name)

            except:
                log = open("log.txt", "a+")
                log.write(str(datetime.now()) + ": Error in file " +x+"\r \n")
                pass

    log = open("log.txt", "a+")
    log.write(str(datetime.now()) + ": " + folder +" written succesfully \r \n")


df_final = pd.DataFrame.from_dict(dict_final, orient='index')
write_csv(df_final, "./Output/final_csv.csv")

log.close()
```

The XMLs look like this

```
<clinical_study>
<!--
 This xml conforms to an XML Schema at:
    https://clinicaltrials.gov/ct2/html/images/info/public.xsd 
-->
<required_header>
<download_date>
ClinicalTrials.gov processed this data on March 20, 2020
</download_date>
<link_text>Link to the current ClinicalTrials.gov record.</link_text>
<url>https://clinicaltrials.gov/show/NCT03261284</url>
</required_header>
<id_info>
<org_study_id>2017-P-032</org_study_id>
<nct_id>NCT03261284</nct_id>
</id_info>
<brief_title>
D-dimer to Guide Anticoagulation Therapy in Patients With Atrial Fibrillation
</brief_title>
<acronym>DATA-AF</acronym>
<official_title>
D-dimer to Determine Intensity of Anticoagulation to Reduce Clinical Outcomes in Patients With Atrial Fibrillation
</official_title>
<sponsors>
<lead_sponsor>
<agency>Wuhan Asia Heart Hospital</agency>
<agency_class>Other</agency_class>
</lead_sponsor>
</sponsors>
<source>Wuhan Asia Heart Hospital</source>
<oversight_info>
<has_dmc>Yes</has_dmc>
<is_fda_regulated_drug>No</is_fda_regulated_drug>
<is_fda_regulated_device>No</is_fda_regulated_device>
</oversight_info>
<brief_summary>
<textblock>
This was a prospective, three arms, randomized controlled study.
</textblock>
</brief_summary>
<detailed_description>
<textblock>
D-dimer testing is performed in AF Patients receiving warfarin therapy (target INR:1.5-2.5) in Wuhan Asia Heart Hospital. Patients with elevated d-dimer levels (>0.5ug/ml FEU) were SCREENED AND RANDOMIZED to three groups at a ratio of 1:1:1. First, NOAC group,the anticoagulant was switched to Dabigatran (110mg,bid) when elevated d-dimer level was detected during warfarin therapy.Second,Higher-INR group, INR was adjusted to higher level (INR:2.0-3.0) when elevated d-dimer level was detected during warfarin therapy. Third, control group, patients with elevated d-dimer levels have no change in warfarin therapy. Warfarin is monitored once a month by INR ,and dabigatran dose not need monitor. All patients were followed up for 24 months until the occurrence of endpoints, including bleeding events, thrombotic events and all-cause deaths.
</textblock>
</detailed_description>
<overall_status>Enrolling by invitation</overall_status>
<start_date type="Anticipated">March 1, 2019</start_date>
<completion_date type="Anticipated">May 30, 2020</completion_date>
<primary_completion_date type="Anticipated">February 28, 2020</primary_completion_date>
<phase>N/A</phase>
<study_type>Interventional</study_type>
<has_expanded_access>No</has_expanded_access>
<study_design_info>
<allocation>Randomized</allocation>
<intervention_model>Parallel Assignment</intervention_model>
<primary_purpose>Treatment</primary_purpose>
<masking>None (Open Label)</masking>
</study_design_info>
<primary_outcome>
<measure>Thrombotic events</measure>
<time_frame>24 months</time_frame>
<description>
Stroke, DVT, PE, Peripheral arterial embolism, ACS etc.
</description>
</primary_outcome>
<primary_outcome>
<measure>hemorrhagic events</measure>
<time_frame>24 months</time_frame>
<description>cerebral hemorrhage,Gastrointestinal bleeding etc.</description>
</primary_outcome>
<secondary_outcome>
<measure>all-cause deaths</measure>
<time_frame>24 months</time_frame>
</secondary_outcome>
<number_of_arms>3</number_of_arms>
<enrollment type="Anticipated">600</enrollment>
<condition>Atrial Fibrillation</condition>
<condition>Thrombosis</condition>
<condition>Hemorrhage</condition>
<condition>Anticoagulant Adverse Reaction</condition>
<arm_group>
<arm_group_label>DOAC group</arm_group_label>
<arm_group_type>Experimental</arm_group_type>
<description>
Patients with elevated d-dimer levels was switched to DOAC (dabigatran 150mg, bid).
</description>
</arm_group>
<arm_group>
<arm_group_label>Higher-INR group</arm_group_label>
<arm_group_type>Experimental</arm_group_type>
<description>
Patients' target INR was adjusted from 1.5-2.5 to 2.0-3.0 by adding warfarin dose.
</description>
</arm_group>
<arm_group>
<arm_group_label>Control group</arm_group_label>
<arm_group_type>No Intervention</arm_group_type>
<description>
Patients continue previous strategy without change.
</description>
</arm_group>
<intervention>
<intervention_type>Drug</intervention_type>
<intervention_name>Dabigatran Etexilate 150 MG [Pradaxa]</intervention_name>
<description>Dabigatran Etexilate 150mg,bid</description>
<arm_group_label>DOAC group</arm_group_label>
<other_name>Pradaxa</other_name>
</intervention>
<intervention>
<intervention_type>Drug</intervention_type>
<intervention_name>Warfarin Pill</intervention_name>
<description>Add warfarin dose according to INR values.</description>
<arm_group_label>Higher-INR group</arm_group_label>
</intervention>
<eligibility>
<criteria>
<textblock>
Inclusion Criteria: - Patients with non-valvular atrial fibrillation - Receiving warfarin therapy Exclusion Criteria: - Patients who had suffered from recent (within 3 months) myocardial infarction, ischemic stroke, deep vein thrombosis, cerebral hemorrhages, or other serious diseases. - Those who had difficulty in compliance or were unavailable for follow-up.
</textblock>
</criteria>
<gender>All</gender>
<minimum_age>18 Years</minimum_age>
<maximum_age>75 Years</maximum_age>
<healthy_volunteers>No</healthy_volunteers>
</eligibility>
<overall_official>
<last_name>Zhenlu ZHANG, MD,PhD</last_name>
<role>Study Director</role>
<affiliation>Wuhan Asia Heart Hospital</affiliation>
</overall_official>
<location>
<facility>
<name>Zhang litao</name>
<address>
<city>Wuhan</city>
<state>Hubei</state>
<zip>430022</zip>
<country>China</country>
</address>
</facility>
</location>
<location_countries>
<country>China</country>
</location_countries>
<verification_date>March 2019</verification_date>
<study_first_submitted>August 22, 2017</study_first_submitted>
<study_first_submitted_qc>August 23, 2017</study_first_submitted_qc>
<study_first_posted type="Actual">August 24, 2017</study_first_posted>
<last_update_submitted>March 6, 2019</last_update_submitted>
<last_update_submitted_qc>March 6, 2019</last_update_submitted_qc>
<last_update_posted type="Actual">March 7, 2019</last_update_posted>
<responsible_party>
<responsible_party_type>Sponsor</responsible_party_type>
</responsible_party>
<keyword>D-dimer</keyword>
<keyword>Nonvalvular atrial fibrillation</keyword>
<keyword>Direct thrombin inhibitor</keyword>
<keyword>INR</keyword>
<condition_browse>
<!--
 CAUTION:  The following MeSH terms are assigned with an imperfect algorithm            
-->
<mesh_term>Atrial Fibrillation</mesh_term>
<mesh_term>Thrombosis</mesh_term>
<mesh_term>Hemorrhage</mesh_term>
</condition_browse>
<intervention_browse>
<!--
 CAUTION:  The following MeSH terms are assigned with an imperfect algorithm            
-->
<mesh_term>Warfarin</mesh_term>
<mesh_term>Dabigatran</mesh_term>
<mesh_term>Fibrin fragment D</mesh_term>
</intervention_browse>
<!--
 Results have not yet been posted for this study                                          
-->
</clinical_study>
```

Comment: If your system is running out of virtual memory, the out-of-memory killer could be killing it.

Comment: In other words, it could be my Mac OS killing the process in order to prevent the system from crashing? How can I verify whether that is the case?

Comment: I don't think MacOS has an OOM-killer, it's a Linux thing.